# Installing BURG: ppa not working

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, software-installation, bootloader, burg

I'm trying to install BURG to substiture Grub, on Ubuntu 14.04 (I need dual boot with Windows 7)

I've tried to install burg-manager, to install burg from there. It seems all ok, it doesn't give errors, but
at the start there is grub
there's isn't "burg" folder in /boot
and burg-emu doesn't start

So I tried to install it with repositories, I tried with that bean repository, n-muench's one, and sourceslist.eu, but when i do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I see these lines

```
W: Failed to fetch  http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/burg/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/burg/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

In fact, "burg-pc" "burg" "burg-emu" and the other ones are "not found packages"

How can I install and configure BURG?

EDIT: I resolved it

In "Software and Updates" -> "Other software" I modify the PPA of n-muench replacing "trusty" with "saucy", then I did

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes
```

And the installation went fine! Then I configured burg with burg-manager, launching it, "restoring burg to MBR", then changing themes ecc

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when updating packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-updating-packages)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You installed that from a PPA (n-muench/burg/ubuntu) that was intended for older versions of Ubuntu. It seems the PPA maintainer has not made an version for Trusty available in the PPA. Go to [Launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/~n-muench) and contact the PPA maintainer directly.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the burg PPA has not been (yet) updated for Trusty (14.04):

[image]